# Create a case using custom button in a Account object

Tags: visualforce

My scenario is to create a Custom button in Account object while clicking that button it show some required field in Case their I want to add submit custom button after clicking that it will create a case record from that account.

I am pretty new to Salesforce development. Can anyone give me suggestion to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked publisher actions?

Comment: The Trailhead modules on VisualForce are helpful here. You simply need a VF page with the fields you want on it, then associate that page to the custom button on Account. Try that and if you are stuck, post your code

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom visualforce page that shows those required fields and call in your custom button via javascript.
But i highly recommended , to use chatter quick actions to accomplish this requirement.
Go to Account > Buttons,Links and Actions  > New Action

[image: Create New Case Quick Action]

Next step is , setup user layout (Which fields will be shown on screen)

[image]

Last step is , adding this action in to quick chatter actions.
[image]

Finally , it will be look like below :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your replay. actually i want to do this in visualforce